# Check if username exist and send verification mail if account is made

Tags: php, sql, registration

Something goes wrong with my query if I use the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function to escape a SQL injection. If a user is created I want to send a activation email with a url and key so I'll read it with a `$_GET` and send to the database that the account is activated (0 > 1)

The connection.php is included in the header.php file.

```
<?php
    include("inc/header.php");
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);

        if(empty($username) && empty($password)) {
            echo "Please fill in all the details";
        }

        $username_check_sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($username)."'";
        $username_check_query = mysqli_query($connection, $username_check_sql);
        $username_row_count = mysqli_num_rows($username_check_query);

        if($username_row_count != 0) {
            echo "Username already exist";
        }

        $password_secure = md5($password);
        $new_user_sql = "INSERT INTO user(username, password, activated) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($username)."', 
            '".mysqli_escape_string($password_secure)."', 0)";
        $new_user_query = mysqli_query($connection, $new_user_sql);

        $key = uniqid();

        $to = $username;
        $subject = "activation required";
        $header = "from: test";
        $message = "Your Confirmation link\n";
        $message = "Click on this link to activate your account\n";
        $message = "localhost/examen/activate_account.php?key=".$key."";

        $sendmail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

        header("location: registreren_success.php?account=made");
        exit;
    }

?>

    <div class="registratie-container">
        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="email" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Registreer">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php
    include("inc/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: aside from the error md5, is really no better than plain text password storage

Comment: "_Something goes wrong with my query_" It would be really helpful if you explained what exactly isn't working.

Comment: No values are send on the username and password columns. But before the mysqli_real_scape_string function it did but the username check was ignored.

Comment: Try using the escape function outside of the query code something like $safevariable = mysqli_real_escape_string($username) and then put that in the query, as a test.